# Comment box glitch

Tags: discussion

Sometimes it is impossible to post a comment: if I open a box and start writing both the ping and the text I try to write do not appear in the box.

Only some red waves appear, the waves that usually underline mistakes in spelling.

It all started over a month ago, and it usually happens only in the late afternoon or evening GMT.

Is it a problem of my browser or PC or has someone experienced the same problem lately?

Comment: When this happens try on other SE sites. If it happens on more than this one you should probably post this on the mother meta.

Comment: "*Is it a problem of my browser or PC*"  I run Firefox on Ubuntu 12.04 and I haven't noticed any unusual comment box behaviour.  What browser do you use and on what platform?

Comment: I'm 90% sure this is a quirk of the browser, anyway.